# Cucumber: Running features parallely in 4.2

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

As announced, cucumber had released parallel feature on version 4.0 but I could not find any sample code regard this. 
Can anyone provide a sample cucumber-jvm testng implementation in 4.0 onward. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look on this example http://grasshopper.tech/283/ from [@Grasshopper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4512398/grasshopper)

Comment: Any other examples?

Comment: What do you miss? What have you tried already?

Comment: Have you looked at the samples repository [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-calculator-testng/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/calculator/RunCukesTest.java)

Comment: If you are not bounded to cucumber, you can try [Gherkin with QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) which is extension for TestNG and supports all TestNG features including running scenarios in parrallel.